# Can Axios differentiate between "no network" and "network disconnected"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, axios

Is it possible for Axios to differentiate between the following:

- A request which fails because the client has no network connection at
  the point when the request was made - (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).
- A request which fails because network connectivity is lost *after* the 
  request was made but *before* the response was received - (ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED).

It seems that in both cases, all we get back is a rather unhelpful "Network Error" message...

The Axios documentation (https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) suggests that in the latter case, `error.request` should be populated, but I have been unable to replicate *any* scenario where `error.request` exists. In both of the above scenarios, I get an error object looking like this:

```
{
  config: { ... },
  response: undefined,
  message: "Network Error",
  stack: "Error: Network Error at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1636:15) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1170:14)"
}
```

Comment: since axios is a wrapper around XMLHttpRequest I believe it is not related to axios in any way. As for XHR found some information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/How_to_check_the_secruity_state_of_an_XMLHTTPRequest_over_SSL
but it say special `.status` values are available only in XUL runner and extension's code

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exacly if you can get **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** but **ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED** you can get use native web Network Information API,take a look on snippet bellow:

```js
var connection = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnection;
console.log(connection);
```

When `connection.type: "none"` mean that you are `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`, maybe you can explore this solution.

you can read complete documention [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebAPI/Network_Information), cya

Comment: That doesn't help to identify whether the network connection was dropped before the request was made, or when it was in progress... but it ought to be possible to write a request interceptor which checks the current connection status, and if this is disconnected we can raise an error to represent the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED state, any other network errors which occur after the request is sent can therefore be interpreted as ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED. Probably. Will do some further work to see if this works as expected.

Comment: So, `navigator.connection` change every time that connection has some modification.

Comment: So we could listen out for network connectivity changes via `navigator.connection.onchange` - although only in compatible browsers (Chrome and Opera) - or better still, using the global `online` and `offline` events [as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events)...